# Biztalk Message Promotions

Tags: biztalk

I'm relatively new to Biztalk and I'm having a bit of hassle with this:

I have built a simple orchestration, hooked it up correctly to a receive port, I'm using the correct schema and map and the orchestration seems to be subscribing ok.
However, when the file I want to process gets picked up at the port I'm getting the 'could not be routed because no subscribers were found' error.
I ran a HAT query and can see the orch has an active subsription to the correct thing, is there anything else I can check on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a futher test:

a) create a sendport (FILE)
b) add a filter to it; BTS.ReceivePortName = 
c) grab the resulting file - it should be the XML thats produced by your Custom PL
d) Use this file with a receive location using an XML Receive PL and see how your orchestration reacts to

This will at least rule out a Pipeline issue...

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Is your port hooked directly to the orchestration or is the orchestration picking the message up from the message box? Has the orchestration receive been set to Activate?
What does your subscription filter look like for the orchestration?

Answer (score 0):

Check your pipeline is XMLReceive. This will promote the MessageType property and hopefully your orchestration will subscribe successfully.

Comment: its a text file im receiving in so I have a custom pipeline with a flat file dissassembler, which is hooked into the correct schema...

Answer (score 0):

Find the failed message in HAT and look at the body of the message. Copy it out and then run validate it against the schema of the message you are expecting. If it doesn't validate then you have set your flat file disassembler up incorrectly.